# Trouble compiling cython code

Tags: python, windows, mingw, cython

I'm currently using the basic [cython tutorial](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html) where I convert a .pyx file using the command python setup.py build_ext --inplace, however when I try to import the file in my console, nothing happens. It recognizes that it is a valid module name though clearly isn't executing properly. I have followed this guide and everything works up to the import step.

Any insight to this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: download pycharm(im sure all ide's can do debugging but pycharm makes it sooo easy) ... use a breakpoint to examine what you have imported.  try printing `helloworld.__file__` to see what you are importing ... try typing `dir(helloworld)` and see what methods are available ...

Comment: PyCharm only supports cython in the professional version unfortunately and I cannot afford a license. Upon analyzing it, it appears the setup properly codes all the necessary conversions, however it doesn't retain the .pyx source code and I am unsure as to why that is.

Comment: Did you try the next example that uses `pyximport`?

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered similar behavior when converting an existing script: I was using the following condition to execute code when the script was called from command line:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ....
```

When the script is compiled into a module and imported, condition is not true anymore and the code is not executed. The solution was to remove the condition (and making sure that it's the correct approach given the structure of the project).